# The Search results separator line is not of the correct length with June 2018 design

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, left-navigation

Today, new design.
Today, new UI issue.

[image]

Note: screenshot done with user settings "*Hide left navigation*".

Answer (score 1):

Completely normal, the code is performing well. The results box is bigger than the search box:

[image]

The problem exists with both, left navigation enabled or disabled.

It could be easily solved by defining a new width or margin in any of the two divs.

Or by removing that `"margin-left: -24px"` in `<div class="flush-left js-search-results">`

[image]